# Badge icon resource/view

Tags: iphone

Is there a built in badge icon like the info icon so that I can show status updates on other views in my app? It's easy enough to duplicate manually but I'd like to use a built in resource if it's available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [CustomBadge](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/08/eigene-custom-iphone-ipad-badges-erstellen/), the site is in German, but theres sample source code there.

You can also steal a badge from a tabbar view like this:

### .h

```
IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabbarItem;
UIView *badgeView;
```

### .m

```
badgeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,100, 32, 32)];
badgeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
badgeView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[badgeView addSubview:[((UIView *)[tabbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
```

and to set the value for that badge:

```
tabbarItem.badgeValue = unreadCount;
```

*Note that you don't have to use a UITabbar thats visible in your app, you are simple stealing the badge resource.*

Comment: You are using a private implementation detail which may cause your app to be rejected or cause it to crash on future version of the iOS.

Comment: It absolutely wont get rejected and it certainly doesn't crash. I have used this method in a few of my apps that are in the iTunes AppStore. Urban Airship (a 3rd party Push Notification provider) also uses this method in their AirMail feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not available for developers since Apple doesn't like to reuse assets for different purposes. Those badges have one definitive and simple purpose -- show the number of updates on the app icon. That's the only purpose they serve.